# HTML/Javascript Hex to RGB and RGB to Hex Color Converter

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, ecmascript-6, dom

I have recently started learning JavaScript (A great language) and decided to start a small project which consists of a website with two inputs, one for hexadecimal input, and one for RGB input. When the user enters a valid color in either of the two inputs, then the background color of the website changes and the other input is updated with the same color in its corresponding format. Here is my code (CSS removed, as it doesn't pertain to the logic):

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";
    
    window.onload = function() {
        let initialColorChoices = [
            "#0c6",
            "#099",
            "#c0c",
            "#39f",
            "#fa0",
            "#affd1b",
            "#d53e78",
            "#e04857",
            "#0cca9a",
            "#e6e600"
        ];
        
        let randomColor = initialColorChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
        
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
        
        let hexInput = document.getElementById("hex");
        let rgbInput = document.getElementById("rgb");
        
        hexInput.value = randomColor;
        rgbInput.value = convertHexToRGB(randomColor);
        
        // I've heard of something called arrow functions, how could 
        // I use those here?
        hexInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
            if (isValidColor(this.value)) {
                rgbInput.value = convertHexToRGB(this.value);
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
            }  
        });
        
        rgbInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
            if (isValidColor(this.value)) {
                hexInput.value = convertRGBToHex(this.value);
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = convertRGBToHex(this.value);
            } 
        });
    };
    
    function convertHexToRGB(hexString) {
        let rgbColorValues = [];
        
        if (!isValidColor(hexString)) {
            return "";
        }
        
        if (hexString.length == 4) {
            for (const character of hexString.slice(1)) { // Excluding the #
                rgbColorValues.push(parseInt(character + character, 16));
            }
        }
        else {
            for (let i = 1; i < 7; i += 2) { // Starting at 1 to exclude #
                rgbColorValues.push(parseInt(hexString[i] + hexString[i + 1], 16));
            }
        }
        
        return `rgb(${rgbColorValues[0]}, ${rgbColorValues[1]}, ${rgbColorValues[2]})`;
    }
    
    function convertRGBToHex(rgbString) {
        let hexString = "#";
        
        if (!isValidColor(rgbString))
        {
            return "";
        }
        
        let rgbColorValues = rgbString.replace(/(\s)|(rgb\()|(\))/g, '') // Isolate the RGB colors by removing spaces, rgb(, and )
            .split(",") // Convert to string array
            .map(Number); // Convert to number array
        
        for (const color of rgbColorValues) {
            let currentColorString = color.toString(16);
            
            if (currentColorString.length < 2) {
                hexString += "0";
            }
            
            hexString += currentColorString;
        }
        
        return hexString;
    }
    
    function isValidColor(colorString) {
        const hexRegex = /^(#[0-9A-F]{3})|(#[0-9A-F]{6})$/i;
        const rgbRegex = /^rgb\(\s*\d{1,3}\s*,\s*\d{1,3}\s*,\s*\d{1,3}\s*\)$/;
        
        if (hexRegex.test(colorString)) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (rgbRegex.test(colorString)) {
            let rgbColorValues = colorString.replace(/(\s)|(rgb\()|(\))/g, '') // Isolate the RGB colors by removing spaces, rgb(, and )
                .split(",") // Convert to string array
                .map(Number); // Convert to number array
                        
            for (const color of rgbColorValues) {
                if (color < 0 || color > 255) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Color Converter</title>
        
        <link href="resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <input class="color-input" id="hex" type="text" placeholder="Hex"/>
            <h1 id="heading">Color Converter</h1>
            <input class="color-input" id="rgb" type="text" placeholder="RGB"/>
        </div>
        <script src="resources/js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Ignore all the extra CSS classes, they are there for styling)

Here are the specific questions I want answered in this Code Review:

1. Does my code use good JS/ES6 programming practices and proper coding style? (I tried to follow the [airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) style guide for this)
2. Is my code well-structured and well-written?
3. Should I give the IIFE function in my JS a name, so that it can be tested using a framework like [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) (Maybe if I wanted to extract these functions into a small plugin), or should this code be structured differently in order to make it more maintainable and testable? (I believe I currently cannot access these functions inside this *anonymous* function)

Comment: There is a bug. `rgb(100,4,100)` converts to invalid color `#64464` hex values less than 16 are missing leading zero.

Comment: @Blindman67 I didn't realize that! What is the policy for such problems here? Should I make a change to the code? (I am reluctant since that could be considered as you still doing a code review)

Comment: Change the code to remove the bug. Generally the code for review should be bug free.

Comment: @Blindman67 I have fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your Questions

> 1. Does my code use good JS/ES6 programming practices and proper coding style? (I tried to follow the airbnb style guide for this)

For the most part I would say *Yes*. It caches DOM references in variables, though those could be stored in constants:

> ```
> let hexInput = document.getElementById("hex");
> let rgbInput = document.getElementById("rgb");
> ```

Because those are never re-assigned, it is wise to default to using the [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) keyword until a good reason for re-assingment arises.

```
const hexInput = document.getElementById("hex");
const rgbInput = document.getElementById("rgb");
```

> 2. Is my code well structured and well written?

For the most part I would say *Yes*. However I do notice that the convert functions create a local variable (e.g. `let rgbColorValues = [];`) and then if the input value isn't valid, an empty string is returned. One could argue that the valid input check should come before declaring the local variable, lest memory be wasted (though in a small SPA like this it will likely be negligible).

> 3. Should I give the IIFE function in my JS a name, so that it can be tested using a framework like Mocha (Maybe if I wanted to extract these functions into a small plugin), or should this code be structured differently in order to make it more maintainable and testable? (I believe I currently cannot access these functions inside this anonymous function)

I don't think giving it a name would be useful, though if you wanted to expose the methods, then perhaps the [revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) would be good to follow for that.

> 4. *[from comment]* Would my code benefit from separation into different files (Or even modules)? Say if I separated the color functions and UI into different files, and then used the revealing module pattern on the color functions? (Maybe I could move them into a class. I think that way I would be able to easily unit test my code easily)

With the current code, it seems like separating the functions into separate files would be a lot of extra network loading. I can't think of much of a benefit for that but if you have one then perhaps it would be worth it.

### Other feedback

#### Arrow functions

> ```
> // I've heard of something called arrow functions, how could 
> // I use those here?
> ```

The biggest change would be removing the keyword `function`, and adding an *arrow* (i.e. `=>`) between the (empty) list of arguments and the function block (since there are multiple statements). Then because an arrow function "*does not have its own `this`*"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)</sup>, `this` now refers to the enclosing scope, so change `this.value` to `hexInput.value` (in the first callback function, and then `rgbInput.value` in the second event callback function).

```
hexInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
        if (isValidColor(hexInput.value)) {
            rgbInput.value = convertHexToRGB(hexInput.value);
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexInput.value;
        }  
    });
```

Then another area that could be simplified using arrow functions is the end of the function `isValidColor` - specifically this block:

> ```
> for (const color of rgbColorValues) {
>     if (color < 0 || color > 255) {
>       return false;
>     }
>   }
>   return true;
> ```

Using a functional approach, an array method like [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) could be used to look for any value that is outside that 0-255 range. If any such value is returned, then return `false`, otherwise if `undefined` is returned, return `true`:

```
return rgbColorValues.find(function(color) {
    return color < 0 || color > 255;
  }) === undefined;
```

And that can be simplified using an arrow function - to one line:

```
return rgbColorValues.find(color => color < 0 || color > 255) === undefined;
```

#### `window.onload` vs event listener

For a small page like this, it is fine to assign a function to `window.onload`. However if there is a need to have multiple functions executed when the page is loaded, then use [`window.addEventListener('load');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (similar to the event callbacks registered for the *change* events on the inputs). Also, the [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event might be more appropriate than [*load*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load).

Comment: Thanks for the review! I have a question, though. Would my code benefit from separation into different files (Or even modules)? Say if I separated the color functions and UI into different files, and then used the revealing module pattern on the color functions? (Maybe I could move them into a class. I think that way I would be able to easily unit test my code easily)

Comment: I added your question to my answer (see list item #4), along with a response

Comment: Thanks for your effort! This is going to help me a lot when I go forward!

Answer (score 3):

The code body asks about arrow functions, so I set out to write the converters with that in mind. In short, they can cut off clutter especially if you can make use of the implicit return value.

Another aspect I wanted to highlight (although not explicitly in the question) was to leverage [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) to give descriptive names to operations.

```js
const radix = (from, to) => x => parseInt(x, from).toString(to)
, toHex = radix(10, 16)
, fromHex = radix(16, 10)
, compose = (...fs) => fs.reduce((f, g) => (...as) => f(g(...as)))
, pad = x => ("00" + x).slice(-2)
, doubled = x => x + x
, limit = x => Math.min(255, x).toString()
, rgb2hex = rgb => (rgb.match(/\d+/g) || [])
    .map(compose(pad, toHex, limit))
    .join('')
, hex2rgb = (hex, isCompact) =>
    (hex.match(isCompact ? /[0-9a-f]/gi : /[0-9a-f]{2}/gi) || [])
        .map(isCompact ? compose(fromHex, doubled) : fromHex)
        .join(',')
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <form name="convert" onsubmit="return false">
        <label><span>r,g,b</span>
            <input name="rgb" oninput="hex.value = rgb2hex(this.value)">
        </label>

        <label><span>hex</span>
            <input name="hex" oninput="rgb.value = hex2rgb(this.value, this.value.length <= 3)">
        </label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! That just shows how powerful arrow functions are (It took me a while to understand what was going on here)! But is using that many and nesting them good practice? To me, it seems like `(hex, isCompact) =>
    (hex.match(isCompact ? /[0-9a-f]/gi : /[0-9a-f]{2}/gi) || [])
        .map(isCompact ? compose(fromHex, doubled) : fromHex)
        .join(',')` is better phrased as a function.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah yes, I actually tried a few options regarding that function; one was to make a dedicated function for the compact- and byte-versions, and a third one which made the decision on choosing between the two. In the end I came back to the single function version as the differences are side-by-side and that *felt* nicer to me. But I agree, it could be improved upon, I'm just not sure how. Is it good practice? I guess it's always a judgement call, but code reusability most certainly is a good thing.

Comment: would an object literal or ES6 class make sense here to store all those different functions?

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith classes make for a nice way to organize code. If you're not going to make use of instances of them, then a module makes more sense. Either way, it is customary in JS to avoid globality of variables like the plague (partly because the browser environment is so chock-full of them). Here, if all the app is going to do is this, then I don't see any benefit of organizing the code. But if it's going to be a part of a larger whole, then sure, a module would make most sense to me.

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith or rather, module**s**, as for example the `compose` function is rather general and in no way tied to these converter functions.